# Problems with referencing workbooks and For loop

Tags: excel, vba

Getting a subscript out of range error for this code. I'm fairly new to VBA so it may be something very obvious but I can't get it to work:

```
Sub Actual()

Dim rw As Integer

Dim i As Integer

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Dim wb2 As Workbook

Dim TAmt, VAmt, UAmt, OAmt As Double


Worksheets("Act").Range("G1").Activate


Let rw = ActiveCell


 Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2. 2019 Legacy"

Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook


For i = 0 To 2

wb2.Worksheets("VBA Input").Activate

VAmt = Cells(3 + (i * 5), 9)

UAmt = Cells(4 + (i * 5), 9) + Cells(5 + (i * 5), 9)

TAmt = Cells(6 + (i * 5), 9)

OAmt = Cells(7 + (i * 5), 9)

wb.Worksheets("Act").Activate

Cells(rw + i, 16) = TAmt

Cells(rw + i, 17) = VAmt

Cells(rw + i, 18) = UAmt

Cells(rw + i, 19) = OAmt


Next




End Sub
```

Debugging highlights the line just after the for loop and gives a subscript out of range error.

Comment: `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\2. 2019 Legacy")`.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` never changes - it's the workbook with this code in it. So in your current code, `wb` and `wb2` both refer to the same workbook.

Comment: ^ On top of that, you made a lot of implicit range references. It's best to be explicit and avoid `.Activate` in the proces. For example: `With wb2.Worksheets("VBA Input")` and refer to cells with `.Cells`

Comment: You have confused `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`.